# how can i to use celery to get the data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, celery, mongoengine

In my celery-task, I am using mongoengine to query data from mongodb. While it come error like this:

```
  File "/home/admin/baymax/baymax/baymax/views/task.py", line 20, in run_parallel
    rolling_task = pubDao.objects.get(id=task_id)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 242, in get
Exception: pubDao matching query does not exist.
```

The code in my celery task:

```
from tppPublish.models import pubDao
@task()
def run_parallel(task_id):
    rolling_task = pubDao.objects.get(id=task_id)
    task_list = rolling_task.task_fregment["segment"]
```

So I try to fix this problem : running the same code outside the celery task which works. So I am confusing why? is there setting in celery leads to this?

Comment: add some logging to `run_parallel` to check that `task_id` has the correct value

Comment: Yes I tried,task_id is correct.

Comment: you may be using a different configuration inside your task than outside it.

Comment: I guess the different impors in python lead to this

Comment: um... maybe. without seeing your code it is impossible to know. is there some way of getting the pubDao object to show what connection settings it is using?

Comment: I switch the 2 models imports, now this problem fixed,but I do not know why

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "switch the 2 models imports" but i'm glad you got the problem fixed